# raspberry pi4 does not work with GPIO 3.3V pins

Tags: gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to test the GPIO of my new Raspberry Pi 4. The circuit I made is the simplest: I have a small fan to cool the board, that works even with 3.3 V. I plugged the GND to the physical pin number 6 (ground) and the +V to Physical/Board pin 11 (GPIO/BCM pin 17 or wiring pin 0). The code is below:

// fan.c

```c
#include <wiringPi.h>
int main (void)
{
  int pin = 17;
  // int pin = 0;
  wiringPiSetup();
  wiringPiSetupGpio();
  pinMode (pin, OUTPUT);
  for (;;) {
    digitalWrite (pin, HIGH);
    delay (5000);
    digitalWrite (pin, LOW);
    delay (500);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled with  `gcc -Wall -o fan fan.c -lwiringPi` and then executed with `sudo ./fan`. However, nothing happens. What I did was to check the pins of my board, from shell, with the command "[b]gpio readall[/b]". The output was:

```
|  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
```

Afterwards, I forced PIN 17 to be high and in OUTPUT mode, with:

```sh
gpio -g mode 17 OUT
gpio -g write 17 1
```

My new output is:

```
|  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |  OUT | 1 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
```

Only apparently, therefore, pins are working properly. However, even when "forcing" the pin to be HIGH, as shown above, (just to avoid any possible mistakes in my code) the fan does not do anything. I tried also with other pins, with the same issue. Moreover, I did the same thing with the common single led circuit, and the led does not blink. Needless to say, if I plug the +V of the fan to the 3.3 V of physical pin 1, the fan works properly. So the problem must be in the GPIO.

Comment: How much current does the fan draw?  It may be more than the GPIO pins can supply.  Can you test with a meter whether the voltage on the pins is changing as desired?  If so, this is a hardware problem and thus off topic for SO.

Comment: [This site](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/raspberry-pi-gpio-pinout,6122.html) says the GPIO pins supply only 16 mA of current.  Unless your fan is extremely tiny, I doubt it runs on 50 mW.

Comment: I am going to check with a multimeter very soon. I don't think is a current problem since it does not work with a simple LED + 330 Ohm resistor neither.